# How to use regular expression from Rails backend in the frontend?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, html

In my Ruby on Rails 4.2 application I am trying to use a regular expression from the backend in the frontend so I can run HTML5 validations on it:

```
# constants.rb
EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
```

---

```
# edit.html.erb
<%= f.email_field :email, :required => true, :pattern => EMAIL_REGEX %>
```

Unfortunately, in the HTML source I see the `pattern` attribute as

```
pattern="(?i-mx:\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z)"
```

which is not what I want.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Why not what you want?

Comment: `\A`, `\z` and the inline modifiers won't work in HTML5, you need `EMAIL_REGEX = "^[\\w+.-]+@[A-Za-z\\d.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]+$"`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Because it's not working. It validates an email like `email@bla` which is wrong.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Thanks. Would that regex be safe to use in the Rails backend as well?

Comment: First, what exactly do you want to see on the HTML side? Second, what are you going to do with it? If you want to validate using **HTML**, i.e. something like `<input pattern=....>`, it doesn't make much sense to start with a **Ruby** regular expression. I would use a string instead.

Comment: @Tintin81: I only know that my suggested pattern  will work as `pattern` value. In the Rails, you need to use anchors, at least `^` and `$` (but you need to allow them), or use your RR regex in the backend. Can't you use 2 different ones?

Comment: I posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `\A`, `\z` and the inline modifiers won't work in HTML5 `pattern` attribute. You need to use JavaScript pattern like

```
EMAIL_REGEX = "[\\w+.-]+@[A-Za-z\\d.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]+"
```

or (though the `^` and `$` are redundant in HTML5 patterns as they are anchored by default):

```
EMAIL_REGEX = "^[\\w+.-]+@[A-Za-z\\d.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]+$"
```

Note that the pattern is passed as a string so that no inline modifiers could be added and the backslashes are doubled to introduce literal backslashes escaping regex metacharacters.

As for the backend, you may use your own regex that is tailored for RoR.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think I am going to stick with two regexes here. One in my backend code and another one in the frontend.